# Android Java Reload Refresh Acitivity Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, refresh, reload

Is it possible to refresh / reload the application in Java / Android.
If so how do I do that in a Fragment and / or in the MainActivity.
Pretty new to Android.

I basically have a date countdown which shows the time to a specific date.
That works so far:(this is done inside a fragment)

```
 if (diffDays02 >= 0 && diffHours02 >= 0 && diffMinutes02 > 0) {
            ((TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.pups)).setText(diffDays02 + days
                    + diffHours02 + hours + diffMinutes02 + minutes);
        }
```

Comment: can you please describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: You should not refresh the entire app to do this sort of thing. You need to set yourself some kind of alarm and then update/refresh the GUI component.

Comment: Well ty, but how to accomplish this

Answer (score 2):

Reloading or refreshing of Activity or Fragment means refreshing of data they are displaying and that can be simply achieved like.

```
onCreate(){

// Do findViewById here and then call
loadData();

} 

private void loadData(){

// load your data and bind the data to views here but dont do findViewById here

}
```

When you want to refresh the Activity again call `loadData()`

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this I leave a message when I am done

Comment: Hmm I could not make this work, little confused.

So do I have to call the method inside my Fragment in my MainActivity?